# Is it possible to add command line arguments or additional applications to Win7 jumplists?

Tags: windows-7, gui, command-line-arguments, jumplist

In Win7 SP1, is there a way to add items to jumplists to launch the associated application with different command-line parameters, or even launch other applications?

There are a number of tools that will create a single icon with user-defined jumplist items, but this is not what I want to do; I want to add items (as defined above) to existing jumplists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! Using [Jumplist Extender](https://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/)*, adding onto existing jumplists is very easy to do with a simple user interface.

[image: Screenshot]

> Windows only allows you to add files assigned to (or "openable by")
>   the program -- **Extender bypasses that limitation**.

*This is hosted on Google Code, which is awaiting its imminent destruction. Visit this [archive page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jumplist-extender/) if the link breaks.